# TwitterKit: Can't bypass Fabric consumer key and app id

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

Ok. So I already had a consumer key and secret and twitter app before fabric came along. But now my app insists on using the auto-generated consumer key and secret of fabric instead. I've tried to override this with:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"TwCnotreal" consumerSecret:@"notrealeither"];
    [Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance], DigitsKit]];
```

In my AppDeleGate.m... but it insists on loading the Fabric id anyway.

My question is: Do I need to load this on every page? Or is it ok to just load my consumer key in the AppDelegate? I can't quite figure out how to get it to just use the info that I already had (since my app was already whitelisted for email and everything and the Fabric one isn't. And since my app has more permissions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  For this one you have to open your info.plist.  And under Kits ---> Kit info:

You're going to see:

```
consumerKey:
consumerSecret:
```

Change those to the consumerKey and consumerSecret of your original Twitter app and you're good to go...

**OF NOTE**: According to Fabric email (which I still haven't gotten to work) will ONLY work with the original Twitter app... not with the one that is auto-generated by Fabric.